# Calculation with an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

Sorry I couldn't think of a good title.

I am working on a ICT related exercise and come across this:

Calculate `alg a(n)` and `alg b(n)` for n = 1,2,3,4 and 5

```
(a)
    alg_a(n):result
    if n > 1 then
    return(alg_a(n−1)+alg_a(n−1))
    else return(1)

(b)
    alg_b(n):result
    if n > 1 then
    return(2 · alg_b(n−1))
    else return(1)
```

At first, what does the code at line 1 do (`alg_a(n):result`)?

A: The question asks me to calculate alg a(n) so lets say I insert 1, `if n > 1 --> no --> return 1`. But what happens  when I insert n = 2.

Any help is appreciated,

thanks!

Comment: What (programming) language is this?  Please add that tag to the question =)

Comment: Since these functions are recursive, once you have a solution for n = 1 then you can use this to calculate the result for n = 2. And so on, for n = 3, 4, 5...

Comment: I have absolutely no idea which programming language this is. Most questions are written in pseudocode.

Answer (score 6):

algorithm alg_a(n) calculates 2^(n-1) and alg_b(n) does the same thing.
Theese are [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) functions. For example for 4 alg_a returns:
alg_a(4)=
alg_a(3) + alg_a(3) = 
alg_a(2) + alg_a(2) + alg_a(2) + alg_a(2) =
alg_a(1) + alg_a(1) + alg_a(1) + alg_a(1) + alg_a(1) + alg_a(1) + alg_a(1) + alg_a(1) = 8

Answer (score 3):

This isn't code, it's some form of pseudo-code. The work "result" just means that what follows is the result of the function. So, `alg_a(1)` gives you the result of `1`, whereas `alg_a(2)` gives you the result `(alg_a(1) + alg_a(1))`, i.e. `2`. Continue to get your other answers.

The question in this case isn't asking for anything more complicated than the numeric answers.

Comment: `1 = 1`
`2 = 1*1+1*1 = 2`
`3 = 2*2+2*2 = 4`
`4 = 4*3+4*3 = 24`
`5 = 24*4+24*4 = 192`

Is this correct?